# How can we flag the post?

Tags: support, flags

I am unable to flag the question I posted. So, I would like to know in detail, with step-by-step instructions, how can we flag the question I posted on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flagging requires **15** reputation per the FAQ.

To flag, click the "flag" option under the post.

[image]

Comment: but how i would be able to know wheather it is being flagged or not

Comment: @nikki only moderators can see "requires moderator attention" flags, but moderators *and* 10k users can see spam and offensive flags

Comment: Your mouse pointer looks like a baseball glove. :)